# Raspberry on Node.js - Spawns 5 node process on first page request

Tags: node.js

I just got my raspberry pi and i'm experimenting node.js on it. Specifically I'm making a web server to serve my own node.js web site. I'm a little puzzled by the process logs though. When i run my node app, a single node process is started as normal, no surprises: 
http://screencast.com/t/8SQY3qDvxkK

Now when I visited the page, i see my process logs CPU spike up to 100% and 4 other node.js process is spawned. Very strange behavior.
http://screencast.com/t/ushqLDINxYV

The web page i'm requesting is just a simple html with a few divs and loading a bunch of javascript / css assets like jQuery, bootstrap.

I attached my html for those who are keen to replicate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta charset="utf_8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body style="zoom:1;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="logo">
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="menu nav">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-th"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone has any clue why this is happening? This does not happen if the my server is simply sending a response message like "res.send('hi there')" instead of rendering html "res.render("hello.jade")"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your browser is requesting your scripts while reading main .html file, hence the other 4 new processes (note, request to fonts.google.com does not result in the new process started). it's a typical behaviour, you should not be worried about that.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! But I do realize that the pi is serving the page rather slowly. Give it a shot! http://missile.io/

Comment: Node is not like apache, which creates a new process for every request. Node is single threaded by design. So, as far as I know, shouldn't do that. Also note the fact that memory usage by all processes is exactly the same. I thinks they are just threads created by node to read the files from the filesystem. Since file reading is blocking, and Node doesn't like being blocked.